# Separador decimal C# y SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Estoy realizando un miniprograma utilizando Windows form que consiste en un inventario de productos para ello tengo una base de datos con solamente una tabla.

Create de la tabla sobre la que estoy trabajando

```
create table Producto
(ID int identity(1,1) not null, Nombre varchar(50)
not  null, Descripcion varchar(100) not null, Precio
decimal not null, constraint pk_ID primary key(ID))
```

y este es mi código en C#

```
        ClsProducto producto = new ClsProducto();

        producto.Nombre = txtProducto.Text;
        producto.Descripcion = txtDescripcion.Text;
        producto.Precio = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrecio.Text);

        int resultado = 0;

        resultado = ClsDatosProducto.Agregar(producto);

        if (resultado > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Datos Ingresados", "Se Ingresaron los Datos", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error al guardar", "No se Ingresaron los datos", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
```

Mi método para Agregar un producto desde un formulario

```
        public static int Agregar (ClsProducto pproducto){

        int retorno = 0;
        using (SqlConnection conn = ClsConexion.ObtenerConexion()){
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(string.Format("Insert into Producto values ('{0}','{1}','{2}')",pproducto.Nombre,pproducto.Descripcion,pproducto.Precio),conn);
        retorno = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return retorno;
        }
    }
```

Al momento de realizar una prueba para introducir un articulo me encuentro con el inconveniente de que al introducir los datos, guardarlos y consultarlos en mi base de datos resulta que en el campo de "Precio" no se encuentra el separador decimal en el precio previamente introducido, en pocas palabras si introduzco un valor de "5.50" se almacena como "550" en la base de datos ya intente introducir el separador como una coma "," pero al hacerlo de esta manera me genera un error que dice que hubo un "Error al convertir el tipo de datos varchar a numeric" al momento de ejecutar la consulta, el atributo Precio de mi clase producto esta definido como "Decimal" igualmente en la base de datos

[image]

Comment: No se si será porque a decimal no le asignaste los decimales... decimal(x,y). X para la cantidad de dígitos a guardar, Y para la cantidad de dígitos después del punto decimal... Inténtalo y comentas.

Comment: Intenta quitarle la comilla simple antes y despues Insert into Producto  values ('{0}','{1}',{2})

Comment: Cambia también el tipo de campo para el precio de decimal a money o  smallmoney en la db, te irá mejor y ocupará menos

Comment: Es muy probable que tu problema se este dando debido a que estas concatenando la query, intentaste usar parámetros?

Comment: DanielVorph intente lo que me dijiste pero ahora me genera otro error " Sólo puede especificarse un valor explícito para la columna de identidad de la tabla 'Producto' cuando se usa una lista de columnas e IDENTITY_INSERT es ON."

Comment: Antonio_veneroso: ¿En donde exactamente tengo que asignarle los decimales? ¿En el gestor de base de datos o en el código C#?

Comment: Por cierto, No he trabajado con parámetros hasta el momento

Comment: @Sasori1264 se hace al crear la tabla. create table Producto
(ID int identity(1,1) not null, Nombre varchar(50)
not  null, Descripcion varchar(100) not null, Precio
decimal (10, 2) not null, constraint pk_ID primary key(ID))

Por poner un ejemplo...

Comment: Puedes probar esto Insert into Producto values ('{0}','{1}',Convert(decimal(10,2) , '{2}')

Comment: @antonio_veneroso Después de asignarle los decimales al campo intente agregando un Producto con un precio de "2.50" y ahora me lo guarda como "250.00"

Comment: @JaphSxas Probé con ese código pero siempre pasa que "2.50" me lo guarda como "250.00"

Comment: Usa consultas parametrizadas. Solucionan ese problema y otros, como la posibilidad de inyección sql.

Comment: Solo por probar inetenta esto --> Insert into Producto values ('"+pproducto.Nombre +"','"+pproducto.Descripcion+"',Convert(decimal(10,2) , "+pproducto.Precio+"), y puedes poner un punto de interrupción después que forma el string de consulta para saber que va a ejecutar

Comment: Ok, al menos ahora sí te guardará los decimales. Como te comenta Pikoh, usa consulta pametrizadas, te ahorrarás muchos dolores de cabeza. O puedes hacer lo que Japh Sxas comenta, para ver cómo se está creando la consulta.

Comment: Ya solucione mi problema, lo que pasaba era que el separador decimal en mi programa era la coma ',' lo que hice fue cambiarlo por el punto '.' ya que sql server no admite comas ',' como separador decimal o al menos en mi caso...Por cierto comenzare a utilizar consultas parametrizadas como me indican, Gracias